# Transfer times for REST API queries vary a lot

Tags: 2013, rest

I'm making use of the REST API to get lists. But I'm finding the transfer times are varying a lot (between ~1 second and up to 20 seconds). How can I improve this? What should I look into?

http://example.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List')/items

Comment: REST is not recommended for large data set. CSOM performs better compared to REST because CSOM requires very less roundtrip compared to REST.

Comment: I've been mostly working with REST. Can I still use JavaScript? These aren't very large data sets.

Comment: is it on premise or online?

Comment: It's currently on premise, but we're trying to do everything in a way so that we can go online at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST services is good. But they bring back irrelevant data and require more round trips to the server.

You can improve the performance of REST call to some extent by setting `Accept` headers (You need to install SP1 in case of on premise). This is explained [here](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/06/improving-rest-api-performance-in.html)

A better option is to switch to CSOM. The library is very rich and can be done using .Net as well as JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for that great link. To clarify, do you mean that using the SP namespace (in JavaScript) will perform better than making calls to the REST API?

Comment: Yes using `SPContext`

Comment: I just have to ask; why would REST need more round trips than JSOM? In the example query by OP there is one single query for items, and this can be made smaller by using `$select`. If additional data is needed `$expand` will give much the same stuff as JSOM without additional request. I would say it is the contrary, the JSON response from REST can be smaller than the bloated one from JSOM